# CsvProvider with semicolon separator and predefined schema

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'd like to create a type using the FSharp.Data.CsvProvider (v1.1.10) to process CSV files with a ";" separator and a predefined schema.

The following line reports an error:

```
type CsvType1 = CsvProvider<Sample="1;2;3", Separator=";", Schema="category (string), id (string), timestamp (string)">
```

The error is:

> Specified argument is neither a file, nor well-formed CSV: Could not find file '...\1;2;3'.

Setting Sample to "", null or not setting it at all creates other errors.

Using a separator of "," and a sample of "1,2,3" works fine.. but that cannot read my csv files.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like a bug, I'll check it. In any case, if you specify the Schema fully, you don't need to specify a Sample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in FSharp.Data (fixed in 2.0.0-alpha3) which thinks `1;2;3` is a file and doesn't try to parse it as a CSV snippet, but you can use the following instead which will work:

```
CsvProvider<Sample="category (string); id (string); timestamp (string)", Separator=";">
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in CSV provider: text parser doesn't support custom separators for sample texts.

`,` is not allowed in CSV file URIs and `1,2,3` is treated as a text sample correctly. `;` is allowed and `1;2;3` is treated as a file name.